# ROR - Google OAuth2 callback phase initiated, then timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, google-oauth, faraday

The oAuth process works fine on Heroku, but I cannot get it to work locally. My app sends a user through the oAuth process, but the callback never makes it to the controller (tested by putting a pry in the create method of the controller it should be reaching). The weird thing is that it used to work locally. I've even reverted back to when it was working to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I created a brand new app, and the same problem exists. This must be something with my computer/network. Any ideas?

**Terminal**

```
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2017-03-09 22:38:58 -0700
I, [2017-03-09T22:38:58.613208 #40471]  INFO -- omniauth:(google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=abunchofrandomnumbers&code=morerandomnumbers" for ::1 at 2017-03-09 22:38:59 -0700
I, [2017-03-09T22:38:59.492677 #40471]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.

Faraday::ConnectionFailed (execution expired)
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['youtube_id'], ENV['youtube_secret'], scope: 'userinfo.profile,youtube'
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'youtube_users#create'
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'yt'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
```

**Google Dev Console Credentials**

```
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Redirect URI: http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

[Image of errors in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suuyI.png)

**development.log**

```
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2017-03-12 00:45:13 -0700
(google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=ecc60cda112ce1f74a28318ac2f2e148debe8afde204d307&code=4/9aFUvRVFluC7fwiDXkstbjZVoiWj684ViSbObLIfSsQ" for ::1 at 2017-03-12 00:45:16 -0700
(google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.

Faraday::ConnectionFailed (execution expired):

/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880:in `initialize'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880:in `open'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880:in `block in connect'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Users/brad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `block in call'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:85:in `with_net_http_connection'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:33:in `call'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
faraday (0.11.0) lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/oauth2/client.rb:99:in `request'
oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/oauth2/client.rb:146:in `get_token'
oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:30:in `get_token'
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb:107:in `custom_build_access_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:73:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:230:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:187:in `call!'
omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:167:in `call'
omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:590:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:425:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.1) lib/puma/server.rb:289:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendering /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Rendering /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (95.2ms)
```

Comment: For anyone encountering a similar issue, the problem was in my omniauth.rb file. userinfo.profile was not working, so I changed it to: `scope: ['youtube', 'plus.me']`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first check if you have already specified your localhost port and added `/oauth2callback` in your Developers Console as shown in the image below. See if it works.

[image]

Otherwise, check the full documentation of [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect), wherein it was mentioned in [The Discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery) that:

> The OpenID Connect protocol requires the use of multiple endpoints for authenticating users, and for requesting resources including tokens, user information, and public keys.
>
> To simplify implementations and increase flexibility, OpenID Connect allows the use of a "Discovery document," a JSON document found at a well-known location containing key-value pairs which provide details about the OpenID Connect provider's configuration, including the URIs of the `authorization`, `token`, `userinfo`, and `public-keys endpoints`.

With this, you may want to also use the following configuration as given in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/openstf/stf/issues/311):

```
export OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_URL="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
export OAUTH_TOKEN_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
export OAUTH_USERINFO_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
export OAUTH_CLIENT_ID="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
export OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL="http://localhost:7100/auth/oauth/callback"
export OAUTH_SCOPE="openid email"

# Now you can just run stf local without the annoying auth options.
stf local --auth-type oauth
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems very specific to stf, not Rails. Also, my origin and redirect URI are correct. They're in the original post. The callback was working just fine, then I changed something in the scope (omniauth.rb initializer), and it stopped working. I reverted my change back to when it was working, but it didn't fix it. I tried using webrick instead of Puma, running the server on a different port, using 127.0.0.1 as a callback, etc. I'm so confused.